# Scatter plot of interaction

Tags: data-visualization

**Is drawing a scatter plot, with fitted regression lines for subgroups, the way to graph a possible interaction in SPSS?**

I may be missing something but I could not find a specific way to do it. I have only just migrated to SPSS from Excel!

My IV and DV are interval scale measures and the factor is a categorical variable.

This is not a homework question!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, that's probably the way I would do it.  You can use the following code:

```
graph/scatter [x] with [y] by [categorical].
```

Then use the menu or the toolbar button to draw regression lines by subgroup; it'll default to linear fitlines, and RSQ for each group will show up automatically.  Just watch out for one thing:  if you have SPSS 17 or earlier, at least, the 1st group shown in the legend will match up with the 2nd RSQ listed, and vice versa.  You can change the placement of the RSQ boxes by dragging them.